# Unexplained inline CSS added to div

Tags: jquery, css, html, jquery-ui

I am working on modifying a pre-made HTML5 template by inserting my own markup/CSS. I went to add a Jquery UI accordion menu and everything looked great until I started tweaking things. I copied and pasted the following markup into my HTML file:

HTML

```
<div id="accordion">
        <h3>Section 1</h3>

        <div>
        <p>Mauris mauris ante, blandit et, ultrices a, suscipit eget, quam.
        Integer ut neque. Vivamus nisi metus, molestie vel, gravida in,
        condimentum sit amet, nunc. Nam a nibh. Donec suscipit eros. Nam
        mi. Proin viverra leo ut odio. Curabitur malesuada. Vestibulum a
        velit eu ante scelerisque vulputate.</p>
    </div>

    <h3>Section 2</h3>

    <div>
        <p>Sed non urna. Donec et ante. Phasellus eu ligula. Vestibulum sit
        amet purus. Vivamus hendrerit, dolor at aliquet laoreet, mauris
        turpis porttitor velit, faucibus interdum tellus libero ac justo.
        Vivamus non quam. In suscipit faucibus urna.</p>
    </div>

    <h3>Section 3</h3>

    <div>
        <p>Nam enim risus, molestie et, porta ac, aliquam ac, risus.
        Quisque lobortis. Phasellus pellentesque purus in massa. Aenean in
        pede. Phasellus ac libero ac tellus pellentesque semper. Sed ac
        felis. Sed commodo, magna quis lacinia ornare, quam ante aliquam
        nisi, eu iaculis leo purus venenatis dui.</p>

        <ul>
            <li>List item one</li>

            <li>List item two</li>

            <li>List item three</li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <h3>Section 4</h3>

    <div>
        <p>Cras dictum. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et
        netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum ante ipsum
        primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae;
        Aenean lacinia mauris vel est.</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

However, when I look at the same in dev mode, I see a bunch of inline styling added and I have no idea where it comes from:

e.g.:

```
<div class="ui-accordion-content ui-helper-reset ui-widget-content ui-corner-bottom" id="ui-accordion-accordion-panel-1" aria-labelledby="ui-accordion-accordion-header-1" role="tabpanel" aria-hidden="true" style="display: none; height: 256px;"></div>
```

Here is a link to the page:

http://englishpearls.net/dev/about.html

Click the light green tabs to see what I am talking about (e.g. "What Are Golden Retrievers).

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is added by `jqueryui` plugin you are using. You can change styles by going to specified files in css insepector of browser.

Comment: Pardon me, but I'm not quite following... How would I go about to insert styles that would over ride the plugin's styling not just on the browser?

Comment: You can use `!important` to override styles. But the best solution is to locate `jqueryui` css file and change styles accordingly. If you are using jquery via CDN (link) you should download files. Otherwise you can override using `!important`. For example `width: 100px !important;`

Answer (score 1):

Those styles are added by the accordion plugin as part of the sliding animation

Answer (score 0):

For building the accordion functionality, jQueryUI insert some of the classes and inline CSS.

If you want to use your CSS, then give the class to your element and mark the CSS !important. It will override the effect of jQueryUI.